# How to create Quiz application?

Tags: iphone

In my app, I created question label and four custom buttons [options]. Ex:- Who is the king of Forest? is question label and options are like a. Tiger b. Elephant c. Lion and d. Deer in UIView. and two buttons to change the contents of **next** view to another question with options and to open up **previous** question. how to create multiple instances of same view with one label and four buttons in iphone sdk. request you to help me to over come this problem with sample apps or with code. thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can explain the logic but not sure hw it can be reached , so check this Example , Link

Go to This link, downlaod the code samples , find flag quiz example - there you finished your quiz app.

http://deitel.com/Books/iPhone/iPhoneforProgrammersAnAppDrivenApproach/tabid/3526/Default.aspx

Hope this Helps!